# Pyodide and print redirected to div

Tags: python, pyodide

Pyodide is properly installed as explained here: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/quickstart.html

I try to get the result of

```py
for i in range(4):
    print(i)
```

in a `div` like:

```
0
1
2
3
```

But it only appears in the console log.
I have tried `await pyodide.globals.set('print', s => document.getElementById("output").innerText += s)` but it doesn't work.